# SSIS 2008 R2: Export "0.0000" to Flat File Destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a column called as `item_price` with data type `DECIMAL(12,4)`.

Records:

```
item_price
--------
0.0000
0.1201
0.0001
0.1000
1.0230
```

I want to export the same values into the flat file using SSIS package:

**My try**:

1. Added tool `Derived Column` with the following expression:

   item_price == 0.0000 ? "0" : (DT_WSTR,50)item_price

Output:

```
item_price
-----------
.0000
```

2. Added tool `Data Conversion` and converted to `DT_WSTR 50`

Output:

```
item_price
-----------
.0000
```

Comment: Why don't you just export the data? Why convert it to string manually? You can specify what locale will be used and whether the file is fixed-width or comma-separated

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Need to create `JOB` which export data from SQL server database table to flat file and store into the shared location.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, The flat file is of type `.txt` and `|` separated.

Comment: @MAK you can have configurable source and destination parameters. Use them while creating `JOB`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your source data from table to query,

```
SELECT CAST([item_price] AS VARCHAR(12)) AS [item_price]
FROM yourtable;
```